# SqlDataAdapter C# WCF Service

Tags: c#, sql, wcf, sql-server-express

Total C# beginner here. I'm trying to update a "Patient" table in an SQL database from a Web Form. I'm calling a "PatientRegistration" method of a WCF service I've written to do so. When a Patient is added, the service returns "True", if it fails, it returns "False".

The app builds, runs and returns "true"... but when I check the database, none of the Patients I've added appear in the table (even after a refresh).

Can someone spot where I might be going wrong? Here is my code for the "database service":

```
namespace ADOWebApp2
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "ADODatabaseService" in code, svc and config file together.
    public class ADODatabaseService : IADODatabaseService
    {
        public bool PatientRegistration(string hno, string fname, string lname, int pnum, string address, string email)
        {
            string connString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\ADOWebApp2\\ADOWebApp2\\App_Data\\ADOdb.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
            string sqlquery = "select * from Patient";
            SqlDataAdapter sqladapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqladapter);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                sqladapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, conn);
                DataSet patient = new DataSet();
                sqladapter.Fill(patient, "Patient");
                DataRow row = patient.Tables["Patient"].NewRow();
                row[0] = hno;
                row[1] = fname;
                row[2] = lname;
                row[3] = pnum;
                row[4] = address;
                row[5] = email;
                sqladapter.Update(patient, "Patient");
                return true;
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }

            finally
            {
                if (conn != null)
                {
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I will remember this in future. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a missing a line in your code...

```
 DataRow row = patient.Tables["Patient"].NewRow();
 row[0] = hno;
 row[1] = fname;
 row[2] = lname;
 row[3] = pnum;
 row[4] = address;
 row[5] = email;
 patient.Tables["Patient"].Rows.Add(row);  // <- Add the row to the collection
 sqladapter.Update(patient, "Patient");
```

Comment: Ah, of course! I'm embarrassed to admit how long I stared at this without realising. Just glad the answer was so straightforward!